# Loading dynamic data in spinner with sqlite database android

Tags: sqlite, android-studio, android-spinner

New to Android,developing an app for IFSC Code.i have sqlite database with columns bank,state, district,branch,ifsc.i have 4 Spinners in 1st i am loading distinct banks.now i have to load distinct state in 2nd spinner from db based on the selection on 1st,like that i have to load 3&4 spinner.i am able to load first spinner but stuck on next spinner.plz guide.

Comment: how to do with 1st spinner paste your code hear...

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setOnItemSelectedListener()` method on spinner to get callback of which position is selected. On the basis of position, you can populate adapter for 2nd spinner and so on.